# 4 pin Molex KK (PWM) CPU fan connector

Tags: fan, cpu-cooler, molex

I'm having difficulty determining which Molex KK connector is the standard 4 pin PWM connector seen on most chassis and CPU fans. Please help me identify so I can buy new crimp connectors to repair some fans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that the connector and the Molex part numbers are defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan#Connectors).

> The Molex part number of receptacle is 47054-1000. The Molex
>   part number of individual crimp contacts is 08-50-0114. The Molex part
>   number of the header is 47053-1000.

Comment: Do you know if there is a right-angle version of the header?